# EQUALOP error message with SML

Tags: syntax, sml, ml

I am trying to create a simple function that takes two dates of format int*int*int and return if the first one is older than the second or not.

```
fun is_older (date1: (int*int*int), date2: (int*int*int)) =
    val in_days1 = (#1 (date1) * 365) + (#2 (date1) * 30) + #3 date1;
    val in_days2 = (#1 (date2) * 365) + (#2 (date2) * 30) + #3 date1;

    if in_days1 < in_days2
    then true
    else false
```

I get this error:

> hwk_1.sml:1.53 Error: syntax error: inserting  EQUALOP
>
> uncaught exception Compile [Compile: "syntax error"]
>
> raised at: ../compiler/Parse/main/smlfile.sml:15.24-15.46
>
> ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
>
> ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-296.20

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You can replace your `if-then-else` just with the condition, `in_days1 < in_days2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to what has already been mentioned, you also ought to use pattern matching to decompose that 3-tuple. Doing this, you can also throw away the type annotations, as it is now clear that this is a 3-tuple (both for the reader, but more importantly also the type system).

```
fun is_older ((y1, m1, d1), (y2, m2, d2)) =
    let
      val days1 = y1 * 365 + m1 * 30 + d1
      val days2 = y2 * 365 + m2 * 30 + d2
    in
      days1 < days2
    end
```

However you could do this a bit smarter. If you have multiple functions working with dates, you could create a nice little helper function `toDays`. In the below example i have just included inside the `isOlder` function, but you could put it at top level or inside a `local`-declaration if you wan't to hide it away

```
fun isOlder (date1, date2) =
    let
      fun toDays (y, m, d) = y * 365 + m * 30 + d
    in
      toDays date1 < toDays date2
    end
```

Comment: "Doing this you can throw away that type annotation." The type annotation is optional either way. Or did you mean from a readability standpoint (i.e. it's now clear to the reader that the arguments are tuples even without the annotation)?

Comment: Hmm, I'm doing this [this coursera course](https://class.coursera.org/proglang-2012-001/class/index), and I think pattern matching will be next week's topic. But thanks for the help!

Comment: @sepp2k, the last part. I will update the text to reflect this more clearly. Hopefully, by now, I should have been giving out the impression that I now, just a tiny bit of SML ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
val in_days1 = (#1 (date1) * 365) + (#2 (date1) * 30) + #3 date1;
val in_days2 = (#1 (date2) * 365) + (#2 (date2) * 30) + #3 date1;
```

Local `val` definitions need to be between `let` and `in`.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I got the same error on one of the other exercises in this same homework:

`Error: syntax error: inserting EQUALOP`

but in my case, it was happening on the first line. This was confusing to me, because I'm coming from Python, where the error usually happens *after* the mistake.

Bottom line, and the thing I wanted to know is this: this error means it can't compile the code as written.

P.S. if you use `let` and `in` you also have to use `end`. (You didn't need to use `val` or `let` to solve the `is_older` problem - there is a way to do it with set logic alone).

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me:

```
fun is_older(diaUno : (int * int * int), diaDos : (int * int * int)) =

    let

        fun setDayNum(diaUno : (int * int * int)) =

            let
                val diaUnoInt = (#1 (diaUno) * 365) + (#2 (diaUno) * 30) + #3 diaUno
            in
                diaUnoInt
            end 

        val dia1 = setDayNum(diaUno)
        val dia2 = setDayNum(diaDos)

    in

        if dia1 < dia2 then diaUno else diaDos

    end
```